# Strange Mysql Query Performance on View

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a view : vcompanyendofday

The following query executes in just 0.7 secs

```
Select * from vcompanyendofday
```

But a simple where condition to this query takes around 200.0 secs

```
select * from vcompanyendofday where companyid <= 51;
```

This is the view definition:

```
 CREATE VIEW `vcompanyendofday` AS 
  select  `c`.`companyid` AS `companyid`,
          `c`.`scripcode` AS `scripcode`,
          `e`.`eoddate` AS `eoddate`,
          `e`.`prevclose` AS `prevclose`,
          `e`.`delqty` AS `delqty` 
  from    (
          `company` `c`
  left join
          `endofday` `e`
  on      ((`c`.`companyid` = `e`.`companyid`)))
  where   (`e`.`eoddate` =
          (
          select  max(`e2`.`eoddate`) AS `max(eoddate)`
          from    `endofday` `e2` 
          where (`e2`.`companyid` = `c`.`companyid`)
          )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you don't have an index on `endofday.companyid`

When you add the condition, `company` becomes leading in the join, and kills all performance.

Create an index on `endofday.companyid`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_endofday_companyid ON endofday(companyid)
```

By the way, if you want all companies to be returned, you need to put the subquery into the `ON` clause of the `OUTER JOIN`, or your missing `endofday`'s will be filtered out:

```
CREATE VIEW `vcompanyendofday` AS 
select  `c`.`companyid` AS `companyid`,
        `c`.`scripcode` AS `scripcode`,
        `e`.`eoddate` AS `eoddate`,
        `e`.`prevclose` AS `prevclose`,
        `e`.`delqty` AS `delqty` 
from    (
        `company` `c`
left join
        `endofday` `e`
on      `c`.`companyid` = `e`.`companyid`
        AND `e`.`eoddate` =
        (
        select  max(`e2`.`eoddate`) AS `max(eoddate)`
        from    `endofday` `e2` 
        where (`e2`.`companyid` = `c`.`companyid`)
        )
```

Comment: cool! it works. Thank u
1st query takes 2.5 seconds and 2nd query takes 0.02 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the select used to create the view by itself with the WHERE clause to see what happens?

If the problem happens with that, run `EXPLAIN` on that query to see what's happening.

At a guess, there's no index on companyid in one of the tables, most likely endofday.

Comment: why doesn't it execute the where condition on the result of the first query? so that it takes only 0.7 secs + few secs.

Comment: When you run a WHERE on it, it takes the full result set then filters it.  If the column it's filtering on isn't indexed, it does a full table scan.