# How to optimize this MySQL Query - inside a view? Performance tuning

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-performance

i have a database with some n:m relation tables and i am using a very big query to combine all those tables. Let's take a look firstly at my database:

[image]

I created two Views to compare performance.

First View:

```
CREATE VIEW `band_page1` AS (
SELECT maid, band_name, band_logo, band_img, 
    (SELECT countries.country_name from countries WHERE band_info.id_country = countries.id) as country,
    (SELECT locations.location_name from locations WHERE band_info.id_location = locations.id) as location,
    (SELECT status.status_name from status WHERE band_info.id_status = status.id) as status,
    (SELECT founding.fyear from founding WHERE band_info.id_founding = founding.id) as founding,
    (SELECT active.ayear from active WHERE band_info.id_active = active.id) as active,

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genre_name ORDER BY genres.genre_name) 
     FROM genres LEFT JOIN band_genres ON band_genres.id_genre = genres.id
     WHERE band_genres.id_band = band_info.maid) AS genre,

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT themes.theme_name ORDER BY themes.theme_name) 
     FROM themes LEFT JOIN band_themes ON band_themes.id_theme = themes.id
     WHERE band_themes.id_band = band_info.maid) AS themes,

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT labels.label_name ORDER BY labels.label_name) 
     FROM labels LEFT JOIN band_labels ON band_labels.id_label = labels.id
     WHERE band_labels.id_band = band_info.maid) AS label

FROM band_info
GROUP BY band_info.maid);
```

Second View:

```
CREATE VIEW `band_page2` AS ( 
         SELECT band_info.maid, band_info.band_name, band_info.band_logo, band_info.band_img, 
        (SELECT countries.country_name from countries WHERE band_info.id_country = countries.id) as country, 
        (SELECT locations.location_name from locations WHERE band_info.id_location = locations.id) as location, 
        (SELECT status.status_name from status WHERE band_info.id_status = status.id) as status, 
        (SELECT founding.fyear from founding WHERE band_info.id_founding = founding.id) as founding, 
        (SELECT active.ayear from active WHERE band_info.id_active = active.id) as active, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genre_name ORDER BY genres.genre_name) AS genre, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT themes.theme_name ORDER BY themes.theme_name) AS themes, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT labels.label_name ORDER BY labels.label_name) AS label 
        FROM band_info 
    LEFT JOIN band_genres ON band_genres.id_band = band_info.maid
    LEFT JOIN band_themes ON band_themes.id_band = band_info.maid
    LEFT JOIN band_labels ON band_labels.id_band = band_info.maid
    LEFT JOIN genres ON genres.id = band_genres.id_genre 
    LEFT JOIN themes ON themes.id = band_themes.id_theme 
    LEFT JOIN labels ON labels.id = band_labels.id_label
    GROUP BY band_info.maid);
```

When i go to phpmyadmin and open a view it takes 3 seconds on both views to show the query result. I am using this view to make a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM band_page1 where maid = '$id';
```

With php it feels like it is taking ages until i get a result back.
It is not only taking 3 seconds it takes even much longer.
My question is, how can i optimize my queries?

Comment: you should index your table(s) and not select all columns, only the ones you need; start with that then try it again.

Comment: Hello, where exactly do you mean? In the view i defined all tables and columns i really need. And in my select i want from that view all columns where maid is equal to a specific number.

Comment: running it in phpmyadmin and then in php, are two different animals.

Comment: Hi. You need to read an intro to query optimization/implementation. What have you read? Please also read & act on [mcve], here in particular for DDL/PKs/FKs/indexes & EXPLAIN for query plans.

Comment: Have you ensured your tables are indexed properly? Also did you properly test it (outside of phpmyadmin)

Comment: It might take so long as you fetch a lot of data between your server and client? Therefore I would go with Fred -ii- and reduce the columns needed. Also you can try to eleminate your sub selects from the SELECT and turn them into a JOIN with band_info. I guess they are executed as often as the outer select returns rows.

Comment: [Strange Mysql Query Performance on View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820495/strange-mysql-query-performance-on-view) probably fit as a possible duplicate.

Comment: That suggestive edit of yours @RyanGadsdon https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17661952 makes it hard to read; there's nothing wrong with their indentation; I rejected it.

Comment: @Magisch i tested it outside of phpmyadmin as i said with php. And there the query speed is even worse.

Comment: @Fred -ii-  i don't understand what extra indexes i need here? the whole database is created with mysql workbench and it auto created indexes for each column. Can you please give further information ?

Comment: @Benjamin i already tried to join more tables instead of doing sub selects and it turned out it was much worse than now. From that point i changed my query for the view to the one i published here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a thing as "over-normalization".

There are standard "country codes" that are 2-letters.  Make them `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`, instead of `INT` to another table.  That cuts down that column from 4 bytes to 2.  And gets rid of a lookup.

`YEAR` is a 2-byte datatype; don't bother normalizing such.

Consider turning `status` into a 1-byte `ENUM` instead of a lookup.

And there may be others.

`VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, and never enhance performance.  Sometimes performance is significantly worse.

I don't think there is any use for `GROUP BY` in the *first* `VIEW`.

`band_*` tables seem to be many-to-many mapping tables.  Their performance can be improved by following [*these tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: This is really a constructive and good critic and improvement suggestion. 
The point with enum improved alot. I changed status to enum and my query is 3 times faster now. Thanks alot !